# How to handle array out of bound exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing function that getting 2 strings.
every string represents version of something.

For example:

String var1 = "1.1.1";

String var2 = "1.1.2";

and returns which string is a newer version.

My code :

```
   public  void main(String var1, String var2) {

    String[] arrayA = var1.split("\\.");

    String[] arrayB = var2.split("\\.");

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {

            Integer number1 = Integer.parseInt(arrayA[i]);

            Integer number2 = Integer.parseInt(arrayB[i]);

            if (number1.equals(number2)) {

                textView.setText("arrays equal");

            } else if (number1 > number2) {

                textView.setText("array A newer version");

                break;

            } else if (number2 > number1) {

                textView.setText("array B newer version");

                break;
            }  
    }
```

Until now everything works fine.

My problem starts when the arrays have different length

( I always camper  shorterArray to longerArray )

if i camper var1 = "2.3"; to  var2="3.3.3";  i getting the right answer.

but if i camper var1 = "2.3"; to var2 = "2.3.1";

i always get "equal".

Any suggestions how to deal with it?

Comment: You have typos in your code, please fix them first. (example -> String var2 = "1.1.2)

Comment: First of all, your exit condition should check the lengths of both arrays. If by the time the loop is over you haven't determined which one is newer, and they have different lengths, the longer version is newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this:

```
public  void main(String var1, String var2) {

    String[] arrayA = var1.split("\\.");

    String[] arrayB = var2.split("\\.");
    int length = 0;
    if (arrayA.length > arrayB.length) {
        length = arrayA.length;
    } else {
        length = arrayB.length;
    }
    int check = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Integer number1 = 0, number2 = 0;
        if (arrayA.length > i) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(arrayA[i]);
        }
        if (arrayB.length > i) {
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(arrayB[i]);
        }
        if (number1.equals(number2)) {
            check = 0;
        } else if (number1 > number2) {
            check = 1;
            break;

        } else if (number2 > number1) {
            check = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    switch (check) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("arrays equal");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("array A newer version");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("array B newer version");
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . the code works as expected.exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @sollo Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your vars to a list and use simply the sort method from java.util.Collections which will do the comparing for you. Example

```
public static void main(String var1, String var2){ 

    List<String> varList = new ArrayList<String>();
    varList.add(var1); 
    varList.add(var2); 

    java.util.Collections.sort(varList);
    System.out.println("designation of newer version is: " + varList.get(1));
}
```